# Write in a emulated card Android HCE (Host card Emulation)

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, hce

As the HCE was implemented in the version 4.4, I could not find information of how to write in an emulated card.

The android website has a sample of card emulation and a sample of to read the card, but I could not find information about the possibility of writing in a emulated card and how to do it.

I am developing a application that will read an emulated card, it will modify the card and write it again.

Someone know if it's possible and how can I do it?

Comment: Any starter projects that show how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question "How [do I] write in a [Android HCE] emulated card?" does not really match the concept of Android HCE.

With Android HCE you do not emulate a memory card, hence there is no such thing as writing to/reading from such an emulated card by default. Instead, you emulate an APDU based smartcard application (note: *application*, **not** memory area, **not** *whole* card). APDUs are commands that you can send to a card (for instance with a PC/SC-compliant contactless smartcard reader). These commands are then interpreted by your emulated smartcard application (i.e. your HCE service) and used to generate response messages.

So, to summarize, you define the commands (based on ISO 7816-4 APDU structure) that your application should understand and the response message format (again based on ISO 7816-4 APDU structure) that your application sends back.

Comment: Yes. I created my "protocol" to exchange the information between my two applications based on ISO 7816-4. The communication is working. Thank you

Comment: I am also customize HCE for my NFC emv card i have created NFC adaptor for reading card like _nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode.Now i able to read card but when i try for transaction AID getting null

Answer (score 0):

There are some ISO 7816-4 based commands listed in this link:

http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_6_basic_interindustry_commands.aspx

I've based my communication is this commands, mainly in the item 6.6.